# Angular 6 - styles only on certain routes

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-routing

I want to display a `sidebar` component on certain routes only, e.g. on the route to which `Home-comp` is assigned but not on the `Login-` and `Register-comp` routes.

So far my homecomp. looks like:
[image]

The `app-root` looks like:

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obviously I am using the bootstrap grid system. I tried to use the `/deep/` selector to change the app-root styles in the Logincomp. like that:

```
/deep/ app-root .container-fluid .row .col-md-9 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

And it does change the background width, but then it also applies to the home-comp. again. Thats obviously what i dont want.
My routing-module looks like:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {RouterModule, Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {LoginComponent} from '../enter/login/login.component';
import {RegisterComponent} from '../enter/register/register.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent},
  {path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent},
  {path: '**', redirectTo: 'home'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
    { enableTracing: true })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

All my comp. for now are dummy. Means that they only show up e.g. `<h3>Login works</h3>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**CSS** is not the right way, performance-wise, to display or not individual components, as they still get loaded etc.

You should post more code; without that I can only suggest to either refactor your `home` component to include the `sidebar` one, or have multiple `router-outlet` - whatever suits your app better.